# Calling the ButtonClicked event

Tags: powerbuilder

I have a script below under a datawindow's `buttonclicked` event. My problem is how will I call the specific button from other event like parent window `post_open` event.

In windows `post_open` event I have the script but returns `Bad Argument List For Function: buttonclicked` message when I compile. How can I correct this compilation error?

```
dw_Command.Event buttonclicked('b_read')


DWO: Datawindow
Event: buttonclicked

CHOOSE CASE Lower(dwo.Name)

CASE 'b_read'       

        SetPointer(Hourglass!)
        idt_ServerDate = gnv_app.of_getServerDate( )
        of_getInventoryAdvice( )

CASE 'b_exit'       
        MessageBox('','Close')
        Close(Parent) 

END CHOOSE
```

Answer (score 4):

The correct answer to the asked question has been given, but I'm going to propose a contrarian point of view: that you should (virtually) never do what you're asking. When you get functionality implemented in a system event that needs to be called from another system event, you should probably break that functionality into a separate custom user event (or function) and call it from both places. Why?

1. Syntax is easier (as evidenced by the existence of this question).
2. It's easier to maintain code when you know when it's going to be called. And for the person that takes over for you after you win the lottery.
3. Today the required functionality is identical, but sooner or later it will branch. Or someone will try to implement something in the ancestor ButtonClicked, thinking it's only going to fire when there's a button clicked. (I know. Some people are crazy like that.) Then you'll end up with some spaghetti solution to keep track of whether this is a non-button-clicked ButtonClick.... Ugly. Then, sooner or later, someone gets hurt.

At one point, I'm sure it seemed easier to just call ButtonClicked. I'm betting you're already teetering on the edge of that decision, and with a little imagination, I'm hoping you'll split apart the script into something more modular. Never regretted breaking something apart...

Good luck,

Terry.

Comment: Nice focus on code maintainability and possible code perversion during future modifications.

Comment: @Seki ... and avoiding answering the question up on my soapbox. *grin*

Comment: @ Teri, Just to share with you the project, its an application for electronic data interchange between 2 systems. and this application will behave independently meaning there is no user intervention at all.  Thank you for the shared point of view and it has something to be considered. im thinking to put the procedure into a function instead, im still on the progress of analysis...

Comment: Yours is the correct answer, Terry. You shouldn't call GUI events unless you're using `call` from a descendant script, e.g. `call super::buttonclicked()`. Note the lack of arguments. PowerBuilder passes them automatically so there's no problem if the parameters change.

Comment: @Hugh For the number of times I've programmed those two (more the `super` than the other style), I never made the connection! Cool!

Answer (score 2):

> Bad Argument List For Function: buttonclicked

That message is telling you that you are not passing the correct type and /or number of arguments to the function (or event).

The `ButtonClicked` event is expecting 3 arguments that you must emulate if you want to call it yourself:

- `row` a row number where the button has been called
- `ReturnCode` a long value that is returned by the action performed by the button
- `dwo` a datawindow object. It is a a reference to the control that was "clicked" by the mouse pointer, you can pass a `dw.object.name_of_your_button`

You could try with the following:

```
long ll_arc
dw_Command.event buttonclicked( dw_Command.getrow(), ll_arc, dw_Command.object.b_read )
```

Comment: Hi Seki, i already tried the script you provided and its working fine. Thank you.